# How to reorder a deck of cards using lists and loops after each restart

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I want to reorder a deck of cards so that the original 1st card is first, original last card is 2nd, original 2nd card is third, original second last card is fourth. I can only use lists and loops.

```
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = [] 

for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)
```

the output is:

```
['Ace of Clubs', '2 of Clubs', '3 of Clubs', '4 of Clubs', '5 of Clubs', '6 of Clubs', '7 of Clubs', '8 of Clubs', '9 of Clubs', '10 of Clubs', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Queen of Clubs', 'King of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', '2 of Diamonds', '3 of Diamonds', '4 of Diamonds', '5 of Diamonds', '6 of Diamonds', '7 of Diamonds', '8 of Diamonds', '9 of Diamonds', '10 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'King of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', '2 of Hearts', '3 of Hearts', '4 of Hearts', '5 of Hearts', '6 of Hearts', '7 of Hearts', '8 of Hearts', '9 of Hearts', '10 of Hearts', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Queen of Hearts', 'King of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Spades', '3 of Spades', '4 of Spades', '5 of Spades', '6 of Spades', '7 of Spades', '8 of Spades', '9 of Spades', '10 of Spades', 'Jack of Spades', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Spades']
```

I changed my code to:

```
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []  

for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)

newDeck=[]
for i in range(len(deck)): 
    newDeck.append(deck[i]) 
    newDeck.append(deck[-i-1])
```

output is:

```
['Ace of Clubs', 'King of Spades', '2 of Clubs', 'Queen of Spades', '3 of Clubs', 'Jack of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '10 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '9 of Spades', '6 of Clubs', '8 of Spades', '7 of Clubs', '7 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '6 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '5 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '4 of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', '3 of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', '2 of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts', '2 of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', '3 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', '4 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '5 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts', '6 of Diamonds', '8 of Hearts', '7 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '8 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '9 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '10 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', 'Jack of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', 'Queen of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', 'King of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Hearts', 'King of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', 'Queen of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', 'Jack of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', '10 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '9 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '8 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 of Diamonds', '8 of Hearts', '6 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts', '5 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '4 of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', '3 of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', '2 of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Spades', 'King of Clubs', '2 of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', '3 of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', '4 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '5 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '6 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '7 of Spades', '7 of Clubs', '8 of Spades', '6 of Clubs', '9 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '10 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', 'Jack of Spades', '3 of Clubs', 'Queen of Spades', '2 of Clubs', 'King of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs']
```

the expected output should be similar to this ^^ but it repeated itself twice which I don't want.

Comment: [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) is your friend.

Comment: Do you want it to be completely random every time you run the code? Or does your random follow some logic? Can you share the expected output?

Comment: I don't want to use random, but it should make the first output card 'Ace of Clubs' stay the same postion after a restart, and 'Kings of Spade' becomes the 2nd card after 'Ace of Clubs' and then original 2nd card 3rd and etc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to reverse the index on every iteration of the loop. I'm not sure if I understand your expected output correctly, but from what I could gather, this might help:

```
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
deck = []

for s in suits:
    for v in values:
        deck.append(v + " of " + s)

for i in range(len(deck)):
    if i%2==0:
        mul = 1
    else:
        mul = -1
    newDeck=[]
    newDeck.append(deck[mul*i])
    print (newDeck)
```

This produces the following output:

```
['Ace of Clubs']
['King of Spades']
['3 of Clubs']
['Jack of Spades']
['5 of Clubs']
['9 of Spades']
['7 of Clubs']
['7 of Spades']
['9 of Clubs']
['5 of Spades']
['Jack of Clubs']
['3 of Spades']
['King of Clubs']
['Ace of Spades']
['2 of Diamonds']
['Queen of Hearts']
['4 of Diamonds']
['10 of Hearts']
['6 of Diamonds']
['8 of Hearts']
['8 of Diamonds']
['6 of Hearts']
['10 of Diamonds']
['4 of Hearts']
['Queen of Diamonds']
['2 of Hearts']
['Ace of Hearts']
['King of Diamonds']
['3 of Hearts']
['Jack of Diamonds']
['5 of Hearts']
['9 of Diamonds']
['7 of Hearts']
['7 of Diamonds']
['9 of Hearts']
['5 of Diamonds']
['Jack of Hearts']
['3 of Diamonds']
['King of Hearts']
['Ace of Diamonds']
['2 of Spades']
['Queen of Clubs']
['4 of Spades']
['10 of Clubs']
['6 of Spades']
['8 of Clubs']
['8 of Spades']
['6 of Clubs']
['10 of Spades']
['4 of Clubs']
['Queen of Spades']
['2 of Clubs']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your deck of cards like so:

```
>>> suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
>>> values = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
>>> 
>>> cards=[f'{rank} of {suite}' for rank in values for suite in suits]
>>> cards
['Ace of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Clubs', '2 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', '2 of Spades', '3 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', '3 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '4 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', '4 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '5 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '5 of Spades', '6 of Clubs', '6 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '6 of Spades', '7 of Clubs', '7 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '8 of Diamonds', '8 of Hearts', '8 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '9 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts', '9 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '10 of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts', 'King of Spades']
```

You can then shuffle them using shuffle in [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> 
>>> shuffle(cards)
>>> cards
['3 of Diamonds', '7 of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts', 'King of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '8 of Spades', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs', '7 of Spades', '5 of Hearts', '4 of Spades', '3 of Hearts', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Jack of Diamonds', '6 of Diamonds', 'Queen of Clubs', '10 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', 'Ace of Spades', '4 of Diamonds', '2 of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', 'King of Clubs', '5 of Clubs', '3 of Spades', '2 of Hearts', '8 of Diamonds', '2 of Spades', '5 of Diamonds', '5 of Spades', '4 of Hearts', '9 of Clubs', '9 of Diamonds', '4 of Clubs', '9 of Hearts', '6 of Spades', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'King of Spades', '8 of Hearts', 'Jack of Hearts', '6 of Hearts', '6 of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', '2 of Diamonds', '3 of Clubs', '7 of Clubs', '9 of Spades', '8 of Clubs']
```

If you are using Python prior to 3.6 that does not support f strings, use:

```
cards=['{} of {}'.format(rank,suite) for rank in values for suite in suits]
```

If you just want to rotate, you can use list slicing:

```
>>> cards=cards[-1:]+cards[:-1]
>>> cards
['King of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Clubs', '2 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', '2 of Spades', '3 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', '3 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '4 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', '4 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '5 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '5 of Spades', '6 of Clubs', '6 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '6 of Spades', '7 of Clubs', '7 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '8 of Diamonds', '8 of Hearts', '8 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '9 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts', '9 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '10 of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts']
```

Or use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

```
>>> from collections import deque 
>>> cards=deque(f'{rank} of {suite}' for rank in values for suite in suits)
>>> cards.rotate(1)
>>> cards
deque(['King of Spades', 'Ace of Clubs', 'Ace of Diamonds', 'Ace of Hearts', 'Ace of Spades', '2 of Clubs', '2 of Diamonds', '2 of Hearts', '2 of Spades', '3 of Clubs', '3 of Diamonds', '3 of Hearts', '3 of Spades', '4 of Clubs', '4 of Diamonds', '4 of Hearts', '4 of Spades', '5 of Clubs', '5 of Diamonds', '5 of Hearts', '5 of Spades', '6 of Clubs', '6 of Diamonds', '6 of Hearts', '6 of Spades', '7 of Clubs', '7 of Diamonds', '7 of Hearts', '7 of Spades', '8 of Clubs', '8 of Diamonds', '8 of Hearts', '8 of Spades', '9 of Clubs', '9 of Diamonds', '9 of Hearts', '9 of Spades', '10 of Clubs', '10 of Diamonds', '10 of Hearts', '10 of Spades', 'Jack of Clubs', 'Jack of Diamonds', 'Jack of Hearts', 'Jack of Spades', 'Queen of Clubs', 'Queen of Diamonds', 'Queen of Hearts', 'Queen of Spades', 'King of Clubs', 'King of Diamonds', 'King of Hearts'])
```

(Note the sign convention is opposite for a list slice vs a deque rotate)